# Compilation error shown in browser CS0246 (The type or namespace...)

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config

I am using some of my project's dll's by adding as a reference in my asp.net project .

Everything is working fine (build successful and run successful) , No error shown there in VS 2013 but at the time of debugging when my page open up in any browser,

> the page show an  Error Message: CS0246: The type or namespace name 'ClientBusinessLayer' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.18408

I have done lots of googling but could not be able to found the solution.

What i am missing?

Even MS VS 2013 intellisense is working fine and showing correct as when writing

```
using ClientLayer;//(My own project name)
```

My project where i am using

```
ClientLayer.dll
```

as a reference is Web_Client.
and error is in the web page`login.aspx.cs` which is inside Web_Client project and executed first.

Comment: Could you check the properties of that dll reference and check if the propertie `copy local` is active?

Comment: Yes it is . @Mivaweb

Comment: @ManishJain - have you added a reference to a project or just a DLL?

Comment: @ManishJain - naah, you cannot add both :)

Comment: Ohh i am sorry there is some misunderstandings I have added a reference to a project @Kamo